# SQL - Union first query will always be first row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I'm new to SQL. And I'm using SSRS(report service) for my project.

The first union query will always have 1 row. And the 2nd union query will have 1 or more rows.

And I want to make always the first union query on the first row.

So here is my **SAMPLE** union query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
   R.TransactionPeriod as 'Transaction_Period'
   PQ.MedicalPaid as 'Medical_Paid'
   PQ.InsurancePaid as 'Insurance_Paid'
 FROM dbo.Medicals PQ
 JOIN dbo.Transaction R ON R.Pid = PQ.Pid

 UNION

 SELECT DISTINCT
   R.TransactionPeriod as 'Transaction_Period'
   TQ.MedicalPaid as 'Medical_Paid'
   TQ.InsurancePaid as 'Insurance_Paid'
 FROM dbo.Bills TQ
 JOIN dbo.Transaction R ON R.Pid = TQ.Pid
```

Take Note: This is just a **SAMPLE** query. My first query is a very large query. But I want to understand this by a simple query

Comment: I'd sure try to run that in a way that eliminates "distinct".. that's usually slower and provides results that many people forget about. Distinct is usually a sign of a "lazy way" of getting unique data instead of really defining what's unique specifically.

Comment: An example instead of DISTINCT would be 
SELECT DISTINCT
   R.TransactionPeriod as 'Transaction_Period'
   PQ.MedicalPaid as 'Medical_Paid'
   PQ.InsurancePaid as 'Insurance_Paid'
 FROM dbo.Medicals PQ
 JOIN dbo.Transaction R ON R.Pid = PQ.Pid
group by   R.TransactionPeriod,
   PQ.MedicalPaid,
   PQ.InsurancePaid

Answer (score 4):

Select a literal in both of the unioned queries, so that the one of the first query is less than the one of the second query. Use `ORDER BY` to sort by it.

```
SELECT ...
       FROM (SELECT ...
                    0 o
                    FROM ...
                    ...
             UNION ALL
             SELECT DISTINCT
                    ...
                    1 o
                    FROM ...
                    ...) x
       ORDER BY x.o;
```

`UNION` can be replaced with `UNION ALL` in my suggestion, as the second query already produces a distinct result and the result from the first query is also free of duplicates in the result of the second query, because the `o` is always different. There's one catch though. In your original query, if there was a row in the result of the second query, which was also in the result of the first query it would have been deduplicated, so that in the final result one one of the rows were present. This won't happen here anymore as the order column is different as I already mentioned. If this is an issue, you need to address that e.g. by using a `WHERE NOT EXITS (...)` in the second query, that excludes rows found in the first one.

And by the way: Your query misses commas between the columns. Don't use single quotes to delimit identifiers. Use double quotes or square brackets, which are special to SQL Server. Also the `DISTINCT` in your first query doesn't make sense if it always returns only one row.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply add a sorting column and order by the ordinal value of the column in your result set. Doing this to your query (adding lines under the `SELECT` statements for the sorting column and at the end for the ordering):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  1 as SortOrder,
  R.TransactionPeriod as 'Transaction_Period'
  PQ.MedicalPaid as 'Medical_Paid'
  PQ.InsurancePaid as 'Insurance_Paid'
FROM dbo.Medicals PQ
JOIN dbo.Transaction R ON R.Pid = PQ.Pid

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
  2 as SortOrder,
  R.TransactionPeriod as 'Transaction_Period'
  TQ.MedicalPaid as 'Medical_Paid'
  TQ.InsurancePaid as 'Insurance_Paid'
FROM dbo.Bills TQ
JOIN dbo.Transaction R ON R.Pid = TQ.Pid

ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want the rows from the first query to sort before the rows from the second. If that's the case just add a column row_order that is set to 1 in the first query and 2 in the second then sort by it. You don't have to display the column in your report.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an explicit `order by`:

```
SELECT Transaction_Period, Medical_Paid, Insurance_Paid
FROM ((SELECT DISTINCT R.TransactionPeriod as Transaction_Period,
              PQ.MedicalPaid as Medical_Paid
              PQ.InsurancePaid as Insurance_Paid,
              0 as ord
       FROM dbo.Medicals PQ JOIN
            dbo.Transaction R
            ON R.Pid = PQ.Pid
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT DISTINCT R.TransactionPeriod as Transaction_Period
              TQ.MedicalPaid as Medical_Paid
              TQ.InsurancePaid as Insurance_Paid,
              1 as ord
       FROM dbo.Bills TQ JOIN
            dbo.Transaction R
            ON R.Pid = TQ.Pid
      )
     ) x
ORDER BY ord;
```

Notes:

- `UNION ALL` is unnecessary.  The subqueries each have `SELECT DISTINCT` and the columns should have different values in each set.
- Do not use single quotes for column names.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Comment: You don't need all the parenthesis as order by operates on a union anyway. And you can simply exclude the ord column from the report.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't down vote it! But you could just get rid of your outer select and all the parentheses, and just leave the 2 union queries with an order by at the end. That does leave the ord column in the resultset, but as its going to ssrs that's easily handled by just leaving the column out.

Comment: @TomC . . . That was just a coincidence then.  My apologies for assuming that you downvoted.  You make a good point about the column being ignored at the application layer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  1 as SortOrder,
  R.TransactionPeriod as 'Transaction_Period'
  PQ.MedicalPaid as 'Medical_Paid'
  PQ.InsurancePaid as 'Insurance_Paid'
FROM dbo.Medicals PQ
JOIN dbo.Transaction R ON R.Pid = PQ.Pid
UNION
SELECT 
  2 as SortOrder,
  R.TransactionPeriod as 'Transaction_Period'
  TQ.MedicalPaid as 'Medical_Paid'
  TQ.InsurancePaid as 'Insurance_Paid'
FROM dbo.Bills TQ
JOIN dbo.Transaction R ON R.Pid = TQ.Pid
ORDER BY SortOrder
```

Union already return distinct value so no need to write distinct keyword